# Disappearing comments

Tags: discussion, comment

A comment of mine mysteriously disappeared on the question: [Is it “rows by columns” or “columns by rows”?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3575/28). It is not a big deal as I had meant to delete it myself as the comment was no longer relevant to the question.

However, in order to satisfy my curiosity, I would like to know the answer to this mystery. Did one of the mods delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted it since you said to delete it, and it was basically noise.  Sorry!